# Ruby on Rails local PostgreSQL does not return results after a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am working on a simple Rails app that has a basic pg fulltext feature. 
My local PostgreSQL fulltext search was working well, but it suddenly stopped working(no results generated) twice. Meanwhile, my heroku app which has the exact same copy of code is working fine. I suspect it was because I did some migrations and "rake db:reset" locally. I had to fix the "no results" issue by running "rake db:drop; rake db:create; rake db:migrate" to start the local database clean.

What did I miss/do wrong?  Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!!

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.scottlowe.eu/blog/2011/04/28/postgresql-full-text-search-is-often-good-enough/). I only have a single tsvector. Here's how my migration looks like for adding the tsvector.

```
class AddTSearchToQuestion < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute(<<-'eosql'.strip)
    ALTER TABLE questions ADD COLUMN tsv tsvector;

    CREATE FUNCTION questions_generate_tsvector() RETURNS trigger AS $$
      begin
        new.tsv :=
          setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.title,'')), 'A') ||
          setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.details,'')), 'B');
        return new;
      end
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    CREATE TRIGGER tsvector_questions_upsert_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
      ON questions
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE questions_generate_tsvector();

    UPDATE questions SET tsv =
      setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(title,'')), 'A') ||
      setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(details,'')), 'B');

    CREATE INDEX questions_tsv_idx ON questions USING gin(tsv);
  eosql
end

def self.down
  execute(<<-'eosql'.strip)
    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS questions_tsv_idx;
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tsvector_questions_upsert_trigger ON questions;
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS questions_generate_tsvector();
    ALTER TABLE questions DROP COLUMN tsv;
  eosql
end
end
```